# How do I deploy a Flask app using a MongoDB database to Heroku?

Tags: mongodb, flask, heroku

I want to deploy a Flask App containing a MongoDB database to Heroku. In some tutorials, it was said to use `mLab MongoDB`, but I cannot see that add-on in heroku. Can someone suggest how I can deploy the database to Heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The add-on has been discontinued some time ago by [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1823).

A good alternative is to use [Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) which offers a free tier and can be easily integrated with Python using [pymongo](https://pypi.org/project/pymongo/)

```
# obtain connect string from Atlas
connect_string = 'mongodb+srv://user:pwd@mycluster-ubiho.azure.mongodb.net/mydb?retryWrites=true&w=majority'

client = MongoClient(connect_string)
db = client.get_default_database()
# query users collection
db.users.find_one({"user":"beppe"})
```

See also this Medium blog post "[1, 2, 3: Docker, Heroku, MongoDB Atlas, Python](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/1-2-3-docker-heroku-mongodb-atlas-python-952958423bea)"